# How to use `feedback` function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Matlab's feedback function is used to obtain the closed loop transfer function of a system. Example:

[image]

`sys = feedback(sys1,sys2)` returns a model object sys for the negative feedback interconnection of model objects `sys1`,`sys2`.  To compute the closed-loop system with positive feedback, use sign = +1, for negative feedback we use -1.

My question arises when we have a system of the following type:

[image]

According to these [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/feedback.html#d117e51709), we can use feedback to create the negative feedback loop with G and C.

```
sys = feedback(G*C,-1)
```

This is a source of confusion, shouldn't the above be:  `sys = feedback(G*C,1,-1)?` These are not the same.

However, looking at these [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/assessing-gain-and-phase-margins.html), for a unit loop gain k, you can compute the closed-loop transfer function T using:

```
G = tf([.5 1.3],[1 1.2  1.6 0]);
T = feedback(G,1);
```

[image]

Why are we using  `1` and not `-1`? This is still negative feedback and not positive feedback.

Comment: From my understanding, the documentation is wrong. `sys = feedback(G*C,1,-1)` would be correct.

Comment: @Daniel not really.

Answer (score 1):

```
G = tf([.5 1.3],[1 1.2  1.6 0]);
T = feedback(G,1);
```

The one in `feedback(G,1)` represents `sys2` and since the function has two inputs, the default value will be a negative unity feedback according to the following line

> sys = feedback(sys1,sys2) returns a model object sys for the **negative**
>   feedback interconnection of model objects sys1,sys2.

Consider the following script

```
s = tf('s');
G = 1/s;
T1 = feedback(G,1)
T2 = feedback(G,1,-1)
```

T1 and T2 are same.

Comment: This is also my understanding, but why does the "Plant and Controller with Unit Feedback" in the documentation show `sys = feedback(G*C,-1)`? It is a negative feedback, so it should be `sys = feedback(G*C,1)`

Comment: I agree that T1 and T2 are the same, however as @Daniel points out, the main source of confusion was the `sys = feedback(G*C,-1)`, and how that shuold have been (I think) `sys = feedback(G*C,1)` or `sys = feedback(G*C,1, -1)`. The last two being equivalent as you, rightly so, point out.